# Identity server4 - Local login not working when IdP restrictions added to the client?

Tags: identityserver4

It seems that local login does not work when I have IdP restrictions defined for a client. I never get sent to the redirect URL. Removing the IdP restrictions everything works as expected. Is there a way to specify the local login provider in the client IdP restrictions?

Comment: What is the provider listed in the IdP restrictions? I have Google external provider so for some clients I have disabled Google. You can put a break point in the Login post action method and see why it doesn't redirect you to the Redirect URL. This if you use their quickstart ui of course.

Comment: I issue was I added 'idsrv' in the Idp restriction list based on the documetion of Identityserver3. Every thing worked fine after I changed it to 'local'